# Cannot able to access array of objects stored in jQuery data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a **list of objects** and each one has a list of configs. Now , I store them in list-items

```
dom = '<ul class="obj-list">';
for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    dom += `<li
    tabindex="${i}"
    data-index="${i}"
    data-resource-config="${obj[i].configs}"
```

Now, if I try to access them using `attr` it says `[object object]`.

When I click on the `ul` I built above, I try to access it from `attr`

`$(e.currentTarget).attr('data-resource-config')`

What am I doing wrong ? Can't I store array of objects in `data-*` attr ?

Comment: this means that `attr` is the object you are trying to access

Comment: Well, you can store objects but not if you are just building a *string*. The `dom` string that you generate will literally say `data-resource-config="[Object object]` after you generate it. Depends on what `configs` actually contains, though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stringify your object in order to store it in the attribute:

```
dom = '<ul class="obj-list">';
for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    dom += `<li
    tabindex="${i}"
    data-index="${i}"
    data-resource-config="${JSON.stringify(obj[i].configs)}"
```

Template string tries to data inside `${}` to string:

```js
var obj = {
  a: 5
};
$("div").html(`<span data-obj=${obj}>SPAN</span>`);
console.log($("span").attr("data-obj"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

```js
var obj = {
  a: 5
};
$("div").html(`<span data-obj=${JSON.stringify(obj)}>SPAN</span>`);
console.log($("span").attr("data-obj"));
console.log(JSON.parse($("span").attr("data-obj")));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store objects as a `data-*` attribute to an element but only using jQuery and only if you use the jQuery [`.data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method. If you build up the HTML as a *string*, then you would get the string representation of the object, which is usually `[object Object]`.

```js
const config = { key: "value" }

const htmlString = `<span data-config="${config}">Some text</span>`;

console.log("This is the HTML that jQuery will use to generate the DOM elements from:\n", htmlString);
```

So, instead, just create the DOM elements using the jQuery API:

```js
const obj = [
  { configs: { name: "one" } },
  { configs: { name: "two" } },
  { configs: { name: "three" } }
];

let dom = $("<ul>") //create a `<ul></ul>` element
  .addClass("obj-list");

for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  let child = $("<li>") //create an `<li></li>` element
    .attr("tabindex", i) //set the `tabindex` attribute
    .data("index", i) //set the `data-index` attribute
    .data("resource-config", obj[i].configs) // set the `data-resource-config` attribute to an object
    .text(i); //just for better display

  dom.append(child); //attach to the ul element
}

$("body").append(dom); //attach to the body

const config = $("[tabindex='1']") //lookup the second generated li
  .data("resource-config"); //get the object associated with `data-resource-config`
  
console.log("config is of type:", typeof config);
console.log("config is:", config)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Do note again that storing objects as `data-*` attributes *only* works through jQuery - it's jQuery itself that stores the object values - normally that's not the case:

```js
const plainHtmlObject = document.createElement("span");

//set the data-conf property
plainHtmlObject.dataset.conf = { element: "plain" }; 

//read the data-conf property
const plainConf = plainHtmlObject.dataset.conf;

console.log("plainConf is of type:", typeof plainConf);
console.log("plainConf is:", plainConf)

const jQueryObject = $("<span>")
  .data("conf", { element: "jQuery" }) //set the data-conf property

//read the data-conf property
const jQueryConf = jQueryObject.data("conf");

console.log("jQueryConf is of type:", typeof jQueryConf);
console.log("jQueryConf is:", jQueryConf);

//however, you can wrap an element in jQuery object

const plainToJQueryObject = $(plainHtmlObject);

//set the data-conf property
plainToJQueryObject.data("conf", { element: "turned into jQuery" }); 

//read the data-conf property
const plainToJQueryConf = plainToJQueryObject.data("conf");

console.log("plainToJQueryConf is of type:", typeof plainToJQueryConf);
console.log("plainToJQueryConf is:", plainToJQueryConf);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```